# Delete primary key in android model class Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have a model class named Post
    package com.example.sudeepbajracharya.assignment.entity;

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;


public class Post extends RealmObject {
@SerializedName("userId")
private int userId;
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("title")
private String title;
@SerializedName("body")
private String body;


public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}



public int getUserId() {

    return userId;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}
}
```

previously i had use @primaryKey in id. But now i dont want to use this primary key so i want to reamove it. I deleted the keyword @primarykey as you can see above but when i try to run my application, it says.... 'Post' has a primary key, use 'createObject(Class, Object)' instead. Can anybody please tell me how can i solve this problem? How can i complete remove primary key fro my model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall your application and run it or migrate your database to new version.
But it is not a good practice to keep a model/entity class without a `PrimaryKey`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Migration for your Realm models.

This needs to be done whenever you add/remove a field, or add/remove Realm annotations to a field (such as @PrimaryKey or @Required, or others)

This way you keep all your data, but simply change all the already saved data

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations